# Toaster messages in web interface

Tags: e-commerce, notification, messages

I am thinking of adding toaster messages as a feedback in an Ecommerce website for small actions, so far I couldn't find an example for using toaster messages in web only for mobile app, and one [example from MailChimp](http://ux.mailchimp.com/patterns/feedback)

**Would be great if you can provide some examples**

Thanks

Comment: Kogan.com.au will show toaster messages like "Someone near you just bought a Sony TV", I think some travel and booking sites have similar toaster messages. I know at one point Facebook used to have toaster messages like "UserName just commented on your picture" - not sure if they still do this. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

As Toast messages are totally based on activity either created(displayed) by users action or background action/processes. It is **best practice** to show/display them in a way that users eyes do not have to roll all over the screen.

The **Best Locations:**

- **Top-Right :** Created usually because of users action.
- **Top-Center :** Created usually because of users action.
- **Bottom Right :** Created usually because of background processes/activity, advertising, chat pop-ups.
- **Anywhere else** - Less recommended, as we are just talking due to users action.

> Above discussed locations are ordered based on priority from high to low

There are few among many examples i would like to share and are really worth.

- [Materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html) & [Bootstrap-Based-Toast](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Bootstrap-Based-Toast-Notification-Plugin-toaster/)- **Top-Right**
- http://muvr.in - **Top-Center** (my favorite)
- [Metro Style with Image](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Metro-Style-Toast-Messages-toastr8/) - **Bottom-Right**

**For more check [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/plus/search.php?kwtype=0&keyword=Toast)**

Hope! You get what you were looking for.

Comment: Also be aware of the accessibility implications... it's not impossible to make toast messages accessible, but in general, any message that appears on or disappears from a webpage outside of the user's direct control can be problematic for visually impaired users.

Answer (score 0):

You can find good feedback messages from here:
http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Otherwise I can suggest Alerts from Bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts